# Unity: Cardboard VR doesnt work after updating to 2017.3.1f1

Tags: unity-game-engine, mobile, camera, virtual-reality, google-cardboard

I am developing a VR game for Android but the VR mode doesnt start up. When I used 2017.3.0f0 everything works like a charm. The game starts in VR mode and I can rotate the camera. I just activated the Cardboard support in the Player Settings. I didnt have to enable the VR mode in any script. Now the game starts like a normal Android game with one camera and no gyroscope sensor support. Does anyone have a solution? Please help me. :(

Best regards Niklas Englmeier

Answer (score 0):

currently I'm using Unity 2017.3.1f1 and works fine with Google VR SDK version 1.120.0, I know that the version 1.110.0 doesn't work, which version of SDK are you using? Did you place the MainCamera as child of an any GameObject and use GvrEditorEmulator? [Unity 2017.3.1f1 using Google VR SDK 1.120.0](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OjWKP.png)